# How should HttpHeaders be configured for requests to localhost if origin is https?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kubernetes, http-headers

### Context

I have a simple Kubernetes setup as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: hello
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  template:
    metadata:
      name: hello-app
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-frontend-app
          image: myrepo.frontend:latest
          env:
            - name: BACKEND_API
              value: "http://localhost:8081"
        - name: hello-backend-app
          image: myrepo.backend:latest
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hello-service
  namespace: hello
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
    - port: 80

---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress
  namespace: hello
  annotations: ..etc
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-service
              servicePort: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - hello.mydomain.com
      secretName: hello-tls
```

`hello-frontend-app` is an Angular JS webservice that can be accessed from `hello.mydomain.com` while `hello-backend-app` is a server that connects to a database and exposes its contents to `hello-frontend-app` via REST.

Here is a stripped-down version of how the REST interface is defined in `hello-frontend-app`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { EnvService } from './env.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StuffService {
    httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
      });

  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient, private env: EnvService) {    
  }

  getStuff(): Observable<Stuff[]> {
    return this.httpService.get<StuffList>(this.env.apiUrl + '/stuff', {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }

}
```

### Problem

The problem that I have appears to be **two-fold**. Both issues might be related but they may also be separate. I can get the above setup to work only if I change it as follows:

1. Instead of launching the `hello-backend-app` in the same pod, I place it in its own pod and put it behind its own service (LoadBalancer) and then point `BACKEND_API` to the external ELB address. Note that pointing to the IP Address (or making the backend a ClusterIP rather than LoadBalancer) **does not work**
2. Simultaneously, I must also change the Ingress to work without tls-authentication. Doing that in combination with 1. and then navigating to `http://my.domain.com` (instead of `https://my.domain.com`) is the only setup I've found where the `getStuff()` request works.

So, it seems to be:

1. `getStuff()` doesn't like IP addresses like `http://localhost:8081` or `http:123.44.1.2:8081` and instead wants addresses like `aaaaaccccccxxxxxx1111122222.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com`
2. `getStuff()` doesn't work if the origin is `https`

Note that if I log into the `hello-frontend-app` container I am able to manually perform all the curl requests work (`curl "http://localhost:8081/stuff"`, `curl "http://123.44.1.2:8081:8080/stuff"`, `curl "aaaaaccccccxxxxxx1111122222.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8081/stuff"`) so there is no issue with the connectivity to the backed.

I assume that the problem lies with the headers, but do not know how to resolve it (I am a system architect rather than a web developer). I have tried setting `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to null or to https://my.domain.com but this does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess the frontend works fine. You are having issues with the backend routing.

I suggest that create another deployment for the backend application. Create a Kube service type of "ClusterIP" , keep port and targetPort of service to "8081"

And then use path-based routing through another ingress config to forward backend service to frontend URL.

Ex. frontend app is on  https://my.domain.com/
and backend will be accessible on  https://my.domain.com/api/

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backend-config
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - hello.mydomain.com
    secretName: hello-tls
  rules:
  - host: hello.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-service
          servicePort: 8081
        path: /api/(/|$)(.*)
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Wouldn't I also need to pass the authentication cookies via the HttpHeader for this to work though? At the moment it doesn't.

Still, it does seem more complicated than it should be. I mean, both frontend and backing are running on the same pod! Surely it must be possible for them to communicate directly

Comment: Are you providing proper env names ? In Yaml you have used ENV name BACKEND_API and in  JS code you have used (this.env.apiUrl + '/stuff')

Comment: Yes, in the JS I am using this approach (https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/) to encode the ENV vars into something that can be set dynamically